# Segmentation fault: 11 in Counting Sort algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, counting-sort

I have written this code in C that implements the counting sort algorithm. I create an array of 10 elements and then I apply the counting sort. The code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){
    int my_array[] = {10,10,9,9,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    int i;
    int N = 10;
    //print the array 
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%d\n", my_array[i]);
    } 
    //define the minimum and the maximum as the first element of the array
    int min_array=my_array[0];
    int max_array=my_array[0];

    printf("--------------\n");

    //find the minimum and the maximum of the array
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        if(my_array[i]<min_array){
            min_array=my_array[i];
        }
        else if(my_array[i]>max_array){
            max_array=my_array[i];
        }
    }

    //check if it worked
    printf("max_array %d\n", max_array);
    printf("min_array %d\n", min_array);

    //
    int range_array;
    range_array = max_array - min_array +1;
    int count_array[range_array+1];
    for(i=0; i<range_array;i++)
        count_array[i]=0;

    int j=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        count_array[my_array[i]-min_array]=count_array[my_array[i]-min_array]+1;
    }
    
    int z = 0;

    for(i=min_array; i<max_array; i++){
        for(j=0; j<count_array[i-min_array];j++)
            z=z+1;
            my_array[z]=i;
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d\n", my_array[i]);
    }

}
```

When I execute it, I have `Segmentation fault: 11`

I do not know why, but I think it is related to some allocation problem, and in particular I think that the error comes from one of the last for loops before printing the ordered array. Indeed if I put some print check where it stops, the segmentation fault error comes at the end.

EDIT: I fixed count_array[range_array] into count_array[i] in the for loop. But now it seems not working properly:
The output is this:

```
10 10 9 9 6 5 4 3 2 1
--------------
max_array 10
min_array 1
--------------
1 2 3 4 5 6 9 9 2 1
```

Comment: There is a typo count_array[range_array]=0; It seems you mean count_array[i]=0;

Comment: Yes, I fixed it, thanks! But now it seems not working :( I am pasting the output in the original question

Comment: If you get new problems, please post a new questions.

Comment: Side note, you could get `min/max`  during the initialization of your array.

Comment: Also please learn how to *debug* your applications. Use a smaller input set (preferably hard-coded so it and its result is well-known) and use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: We don't need a story of "*I got this problem. Now it is fixed. Now I have another problem"*. Please focus the question and provided code on one question only.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes sure, I modified my code using a small array of 10 fixed elements.

Comment: `z=z+1;` should arrive slightly later...